# Periodic tilings of the plane with fundamental domain given by $k$ squares of prescribed size

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, tiling

Given $k$ strictly positive real numbers $l_1,\dots,l_k$, can one decide the existence of a periodic tiling of the plane whose fundamental domain is the union of $k$ squares 
of length $l_1,\dots,l_k$?

For $k\leq 2$, such tilings exist always.

How can one construct them in case of existence?

(Fun example: given a natural integer $n$ are there always (at most) four such lengths given
by non-negative integers $a,b,c,d$ with $n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$?)

Added: One can always decide the existence theoretically since there are a finite
number of possible graphs (given by boundary of squares) on the resulting quotient-torus.
This is however not usable in practice.

Comment: What has the example to do with the question?

Comment: Since every natural number is a sum of four squares, it is tempting 
to ask for the existence of tilings having fundamental domains of area $n$ and involving at most four squares with side-lengths given by natural numbers. A somewhat weaker question is: can one give an universal upper bound (independent of $n$) for the number of such squares (with side-lengths in $\mathbb N$) involved in a fundamenal tiling domain of area $n$?

Comment: Fo you need a domain to be connected?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you can always choose a connected  domain by 
suitably translating the connected components and gluing them together.

Comment: I do not the answer. The question reminds me of this paper of Benjamini and Schramm on square tilings: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1065725179